# Answering duplicate questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, duplicate-questions, low-quality-posts

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is with people who answer questions that are known to be dupes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50358/what-is-with-people-who-answer-questions-that-are-known-to-be-dupes)
>   [Should there be a reputation cost for duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43385/should-there-be-a-reputation-cost-for-duplicate-questions)

Strangely enough I can't find this subject on meta yet, as I heard it somewhere recently, perhaps a podcast? (I believe the one with Jon Skeet.)

**Why do so many people waste their time answering obviously duplicate low-effort questions?** As a recent example: [Inheritance vs. interface in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6188827/590790) My first guess is they find it easy to gain rep with.

The problem is this really hurts StackExchange. Other more thought through questions get less and less attention. There are a lot more 'stupid' questions than people that can answer difficult ones. The combined effort of all the answers (even by +30k users) doesn't even come close to the effort put into the question by the OP.

I really believe answering low quality/duplicate questions should be discouraged. **One way would be to discard all granted reputation once a question is closed as a duplicate or as low quality.**

Comment: @Piskvor: Granted, duplicate, but not an obvious one. I did find this one in search, but you can't conclude from the title it's the same subject. In fact it looks like that feature request was only added as an update, in reply to an answer.

Comment: Oh, this whole question has [already been asked in the past](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50358/what-is-with-people-who-answer-questions-that-are-known-to-be-dupes). Both the question of "Why", and the actual request to remove all such reputation. Which itself has been duplicated a couple times, and itself also originated in an answer from Ether.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/should-you-gain-rep-for-asking-a-duplicate-question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions

Comment: @Grace Note: Thanks, that's a relevant discussion. Didn't show up in search.

Comment: [You should stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: @Won't: Cody Gray replied the same on [the question I was talking about](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6188827/590790). A similar answer applies, as already discussed properly in [the duplicate of this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50358/157047). I don't dislike dupes, but they should be discouraged, especially 'bad' no-effort dupes. Moderating duplicates also takes up a considerable amount of time.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: true true true.